# easy-bluetooth-classic module connect

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth

I try to use classic bluetooth API on React-Native App with `easy-bluetooth-classic` module.

After scan and show all device detected, i would like connect with us :

```
EasyBluetooth.connect(device)
  .then(() => {
    alert('Connected!');
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.warn(ex);
  });
```

But this function return an error : `{ [Error: Unable to connect to: Redmi [80:35:C1:41:4A:17]] framesToPop: 1, code: 'EUNSPECIFIED' }` and i don't understand why.

All devices return this error.

Maybe i need a custom config.uuid ?

```
const config = {
  "uuid": "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
  "deviceName": "Bluetooth Example Project",
  "bufferSize": 1024,
  "characterDelimiter": "\n"
}
```

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Comment: Im facing the same issue, were you able to figure it out?